# How do I connect an Intellij IDEA Ultimate Edition to a DB2 Server for VM & VSE database?

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbc, db2

I am trying to access a DB2 Server for VM & VSE database from Intellij IDEA Ultimate Edition. Please do not get confused by the term DB2 Server for VM & VSE - this is the mainframe edition. Previously known as IBM SQL/DS. This isn't the DB2 LUW-Edition.

To do this, I have select "Data Source from URL" in the Intellij database menu and set the properties.

It looks fine, but the database wants a licence file in the classpath.

I have this file from the DB2 Connect package (db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar), but in which directory should I put the jar-file? In a subdirectory of Intellij IDEA?

Putting the file in the Intellij root directory did not help.

Here is the error message (Sorry, unfortunately in German):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the path to the license file db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar into system variable PATH. For example: `start -> view advanced system properties -> environment variables -> system variables -> path`

Also, you can try to specify it in the driver settings Driver files section the file directly

[image]

Comment: It's great what you can do with Intellij IDEA. Thank you very much.